# syntax error in a join query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query here:
For each country in America, give the highest mountain and its height; ordered by height.
and tables:

```
encompasses : country,continent   
geo_mountain: mountain,country  
mountain:name,height
```

i wrote so:

```
select co.country,mo.name, max(mo.height) as mheight
from mountain mo,encompasses co
join geo_mountain gmo
on mo.name=gmo.mountain
where gmo.country=any (select country from encompasses where continen='America') 
GROUP BY co.country
order by mheight;
```

but i get this error in oracle 11g:

```
Error at Command Line:203 Column:4(second like)
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "MO"."NAME": invalid identifier
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with `mo.name` in the query you've posted, assuming the table structures you've posted are correct. I do see some other issues: (1) your subquery references `continen` instead of `continent` and (2) you're cross-joining `encompasses` by including it in the `FROM` list without any join conditions.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are mixing JOIN syntax - you are using both explicit and implicit syntax. The explicit JOIN ha a higher precedence so the alias for the tables in the implicit join (`mountain`, `encompasses`) are not available to be used. If you want to perform a cross join or cartesian result, then you should use:

```
select co.country,
  mo.name, 
  max(mo.height) as mheight
from mountain mo
cross join encompasses co
join geo_mountain gmo
  on mo.name=gmo.mountain
where gmo.country=any (select country 
                       from encompasses 
                       where continent ='America') 
GROUP BY co.country, mo.name
order by mheight;
```

Comment: My guess is that the cross join most probably isn't intended.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That is possible but based on the limited table structure provided, I don't see how the `mountain` and `encompasses` join.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing your joins on the full table names rather than the alias...
on mountain.name = geo_mountain.mountain

Also remember that Oracle is case-sensitive (at least when I last worked with it).
You may want to do an upper conversion on your join fields as well.

Comment: Oracle is not case sensitive unless you use quoted identifiers. Just like any other standard compliant DBMS.